# How to create a message post between different users

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Lets say there are two users. user1 sends message to user2.

When user2 logs in, he sees a message from user1 in his inbox.

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  subject: String,
  body: String,
  seen: Boolean,
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  recipient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
});
```

Route:

```
router.post('/messagefromuser', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.body ', req.body);
  let message = new Messages();
  message.body = req.body.message;
  message.save();
});
```

I am trying to insert message like above but I don't see any reference linked to user to track who sent a message.

Record in db:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d6b09a0a4b60b09b3c376f7"
    },
    "body": "Hello",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't see any reference linked to user to track who sent a message.

That's totally normal, because you didn't set the `sender` and `recipient` of the object  you stored in the database.

in your `checkJWT` middleware, you should decode the jwt token and extract `userId` from payload and set `req.currentUserId`. and also you should set recipient to `req.body.recipient`. something like this:

```
router.post('/messagefromuser', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.body ', req.body);
  let message = new Messages();
  //add theese lines
  message.sender = req.currentUserId;
  message.recipient = req.body.recipient;

  message.body = req.body.message;
  message.save();
});
```